# Change innerhtml of label when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add innerhtml to my label, when a radio button is checked.
By default the label does not have any value.

I want to change the value of the label based on the value of the radio button.
But I want to define my own value for this.
So the label for value 1 should be: "Label 1"
Label for value 2 should be "Label 2" etc.

I use this for star rating, so when a next radio button is checked, it should remove the value of the previous label.

This is my current html:

```html
<ul class="rating">
  <li>
    <span class="ratingSelector">
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-1-5" value="1" class="radio">
      <label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-1-5"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-2-5" value="2" class="radio">
      <label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-2-5"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-3-5" value="3" class="radio">
      <label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-3-5"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-4-5" value="4" class="radio">
      <label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-4-5"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-5-5" value="5" class="radio">
      <label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-5-5"></label>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="ratingSelector">
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-1-5" value="1" class="radio">
      <label class="full" for="Design-1-5"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-2-5" value="2" class="radio">
      <label class="full" for="Design-2-5"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-3-5" value="3" class="radio">
      <label class="full" for="Design-3-5"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-4-5" value="4" class="radio">
      <label class="full" for="Design-4-5"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-5-5" value="5" class="radio">
      <label class="full" for="Design-5-5"></label>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try solution acc. to you.

You can combile "Label" as string to rvalue variable.
i.e `var rvalue="Label"+$(this).attr('value');`

like as:

```
$('.radio[name="rating[2]"]').change(function(){
    var rvalue='';
    if($(this).attr('value')=='1')
      {
        rvalue='Bad';
      }
    else if($(this).attr('value')=='5')
      {
        rvalue='Amazing';
      }

        $(this).parent('.ratingSelector').find('.full').html('');
        $(this).next('label').html(rvalue);
    });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7wLbyn2c/4/

Comment: Thanks, but this echo the exact value of the radio button. I need to define my own value for every label based on the input.

Comment: ya sure you can do, check radio button value and using switch case or if else to assign label html acc. to yours need.

Comment: You can combile "Label" as string to rvalue variable. i.e var rvalue="Label"+$(this).attr('value');

Comment: Remove all labels html as $('.full').html(''); Check my updated answer as per your updated question.

Comment: Thanks! :) But see my updated code. I use more li classes than just one and the label text should effect each individual li class. So can I define in your code the name of the radio button? So that it effect each li class?

Comment: yes you can using the radio name. as   .radio[name="ratings[2]"]'

Comment: Check my answer at the end use can use in this way using the attribute selector. and label will clear only inside the specific li.

Comment: Many thanks! The only and last thing that I would like to define is the text that is displayed. It should not echo exactly "Label 1". I want to define the text that is display for each label. For example for label 1 "To bad" for Label 5 "Amazing".

Comment: Now, check my answer.. you can use to more options also like 2,3,4 etc.

Comment: Most Welcome Always :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" onClick="getInnerHtml($(this))">
// call getInnerHtml function in all radio buttons and then write the function

function getInnerHtml(thisVal) {
   alert(thisVal.innerHtml());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
<input type="radio" name = 'somename' onclick="getvalue(this)">

    <script>
    function getvalue(ref) {
       alert(ref.value);
    }
    </script>
```

We are just passing the reference to this particular radio button as parameter in the onclick event function and then simply use `.value` attribute used in javascript. You can also use `onchange` event.

**Edited**

```
function getvalue(ref) {
       for(i=ref.value;i<=5;i++)
       {
       $(this).next('label').appned(i);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this echo the exact value of the radio button. I need to define my own value for every label based on the input.

Comment: you mean to say that you need to change  the value of label to the radio buttons value?

Comment: I mean that I want to define the text in the script what is displayed for each of the 5 labels. So that I can define my own text for label 1,2,3,4 and 5.

Comment: check the edited part of my answer, now you can set the label values starting from the radio buttons value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $('label').text('');
   $(this).next('label').html('Label '+$(this).attr('value'));
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nm8ha2p9/1/

Comment: Thanks!! Got it nearly. Is it also possible to remove the previous label text, when a new radio button is checked?

Comment: Thanks and is it also possible to define the text of each label individually not dynamically? So that I can define the entire text of the label?

Comment: yes , you can use if statements to check the current  value of option button and set the value of labels whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did something with pure JS. I hope it helps you. It's on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqpBwq). This are functions I used:

```
function setValue(obj)
{
  if(obj.checked){
    clearLabels();
    var lbls = document.getElementsByTagName("LABEL");
    var lbl = undefined;
    for(var i=0;i<lbls.length; i++)
    {
      if(lbls[i].htmlFor == obj.id)
      {
        lbl = lbls[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    if(lbl != undefined){
      lbl.innerHTML = obj.value;
    }
  }
}
function clearLabels()
{
  var lbls = document.getElementsByTagName("LABEL");
  for(var i=0;i<lbls.length;i++){
    lbls[i].innerHTML="";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JS, no jQuery.

Labels are set in your HTML, so you can easily have whatever you want.

Labels use a class to hide them when not wanted.

Uses delegated event listener, listening for click to bubble.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.ratingSelector'), function (node) {
    var labels = node.querySelectorAll('.full');

    node.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        var target = evt.target;

        if (target.classList.contains('radio')) {
            [].forEach.call(labels, function (label) {
                label.classList.add('hidden');
            });

            evt.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('hidden');
        }
    }, false);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display:none
}
```

```html
<ul class="rating">
  <li>
    <span class="ratingSelector">
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-1-5" value="1" class="radio">
      <label class="full hidden" for="Degelijkheid-1-5">Label 1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-2-5" value="2" class="radio">
      <label class="full hidden" for="Degelijkheid-2-5">Label 2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-3-5" value="3" class="radio">
      <label class="full hidden" for="Degelijkheid-3-5">Label 3</label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-4-5" value="4" class="radio">
      <label class="full hidden" for="Degelijkheid-4-5">Label 4</label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-5-5" value="5" class="radio">
      <label class="full hidden" for="Degelijkheid-5-5">Label 5</label>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="ratingSelector">
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-1-5" value="1" class="radio">
      <label class="full hidden" for="Design-1-5">Label 1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-2-5" value="2" class="radio">
      <label class="full hidden" for="Design-2-5">Label 2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-3-5" value="3" class="radio">
      <label class="full hidden" for="Design-3-5">Label 3</label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-4-5" value="4" class="radio">
      <label class="full hidden" for="Design-4-5">Label 4</label>
      <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-5-5" value="5" class="radio">
      <label class="full hidden" for="Design-5-5">Label 5</label>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```